# Get static block content by identifier in helper class?

Tags: magento2, static-block, helper

I am trying to get the content of a static block in a helper class. So far I had no luck. So, how can I get the content of a static block by block identifier in a helper class?

I tried:

```
$valueContent = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('my_identifier')->toHtml();
```

**Magento 2.2.2**

Comment: can you add any codes you tried

Comment: Sure, see my original post.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below in your helper file.

```
<?php

namespace Custom\Module\Helper;

use Magento\Cms\Api\BlockRepositoryInterface;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{
    private $blockRepository;

    public function __construct(
        BlockRepositoryInterface $blockRepository
    ) {
        $this->blockRepository = $blockRepository;
    }

    public function getContent($identifier)
    {
        try {
            /** @var BlockInterface $block */
            $block = $this->blockRepository->getById($identifier);
            $content = $block->getContent();
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $content = false;
        }

        return $content;
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Helper;

class Data extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
{

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface 
     */
    protected $layout;


    /**
     * Data constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\LayoutInterface $layout
    ) {
        $this->layout = $layout;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }


    /**
     * @return block $valueContent
     */
    public function getBlock() {

        $valueContent = $this->layout
            ->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')
            ->setBlockId('my_identifier')
            ->toHtml();

        return $valueContent;

    }
}
```

Then you can use/call `$helper->getBlock()` to show it in a **`phtml`** template